# Gaussian curvature continuous

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have any surface, lets say $Σ$, which has at a point r, primitive curvatures $k_1=2, k_2=-1$. Thus, the Gaussian curvature is $K=-2<0$. Can we say that there s a small area around r, in which we still have $K<0$?. In other words is K continuous?. If P and Q are the matrices of the first and second fundamental form, then K=$detP/detQ$. So, in other words are the elements of P and Q always continuous?. If the surface is parametrized with, let s say $r(u,v)$, we know that $r(u,v)\in C_1$, meaning that $r_u$ and $r_v $, are continuous and thus, so are $||r_u||^2$ and so on. However for $detP$ to be continuous  we also need $r_{uu}n$ and $r_{vv}n$ and so on. Don't we need $r(u,v)$ to be $C_2$ to make that statement?

Comment: You need $r$ to be twice differentiable for $K$ to even be defined, no? I do think you need to assume $r$ is $C^2$ to get continuous $K$ - you should be able to use the standard examples of differentiable but not $C^1$ functions to construct a $C^1$, twice-differentiable surface that has discontinuous $K$.